# Azure API Management returning "Setting 'config.db.connection' could not be found."

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We have exposed some Azure Functions through Azure API Management. The functions work when called directly and the endpoints in Api Management also used to work. Now when we call the api management endpoints they return

```
[ConfigurationErrorsException: Setting 'config.db.connection' could not be found.]
   Microsoft.Azure.ApiManagement.Infra.Configuration.SettingsProviderExtensions.GetSetting(ISettingsProvider provider, String name) in e:\Checkin package\AAPT\APIM\Infra\Infra\src\Infra\Configuration\SettingsProviderExtensions.cs:19
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Api.Settings.get_SqlConnectionString() in D:\Checkin-Master\AAPT\APIManagement\Proxy\Api\Service\Settings.cs:43
   Microsoft.Azure.ApiManagement.Gateway.IoC.Modules.c.b__0_0(IComponentContext c) in D:\Checkin-Master\AAPT\APIManagement\Proxy\Gateway.IoC\Modules\SqlConfigurationModule.cs:38
   Autofac.c__DisplayClass10`1.b__f(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) +10
   Autofac.Builder.c__DisplayClass1`1.b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) +14
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +32
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +48
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.b__0() +8
   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator) +120
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +132
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +133
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +24
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +74
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +54
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +118
   Microsoft.Azure.ApiManagement.Gateway.IoC.Modules.c.b__0_4(IComponentContext c) in D:\Checkin-Master\AAPT\APIManagement\Proxy\Gateway.IoC\Modules\ConfigurationModule.cs:116
   Autofac.c__DisplayClass10`1.b__f(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) +10
   Autofac.Builder.c__DisplayClass1`1.b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) +14
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +32
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +48
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.b__0() +8
   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator) +120
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +132
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +133
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +24
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.c__DisplayClass2.b__0() +25
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() +94
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +174
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +48
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.b__0() +8
   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator) +120
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +132
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +133
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +44

[DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details. ---> Setting 'config.db.connection' could not be found. (See inner exception for details.)]
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +112
   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +109
   Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +14
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +74
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +54
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +118
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context) +75
   Microsoft.Azure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Host.SystemWeb.GatewayStartup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in D:\Checkin-Master\AAPT\APIManagement\Proxy\Gateway.Host.SystemWeb\GatewayStartup.cs:75

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +160
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +101
   Owin.Loader.c__DisplayClass12.b__b(IAppBuilder builder) +66
   Owin.Loader.c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +123
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.c__DisplayClass2.b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +71
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) +462
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +40
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +70
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +106
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +523
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +176
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +220
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +303

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +658
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +89
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +189
```

Where is this db.connection setting that is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you were using consumption sku. Apim had a bug in upgrade. This should not be happening anymore.